# Dos variables del mismo tipo generan el error 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Single'

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. me encuentro haciendo esta consulta:

```
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Validacion/Duplicidad", Name = "GetLlantasValidacionDuplicidad")]
    public List<LlanHistoria> GetLlantasValidacionDuplicidad(string? IdLlanta)
    {
        // 2024-02-04: Variable que indica si la llanta se encuentra activa.
        string SituacionActual = "ok";
        var q = from a in context.LlanHistoria
                where
                    a.id == IdLlanta
                    &&
                    a.situacion == SituacionActual
                select new LlanHistoria
                {

                    Registro = a.Registro,
                    id = a.id,
                    Fecha = a.Fecha,
                    equipo = a.equipo,
                    Ubicacion = a.Ubicacion,
                    Horometro = a.Horometro
                 };
                return q.ToList();
        }
```

Al ejecutarlo, me genera el siguiente error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Single'.'
```

Yo estoy utilizando la tabla context.LlanHistoria, la cual esta definida por la siguiente clase:

```
public class LlanHistoria
{
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public float Horometro { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
}
```

Si comento el campo Horometro, desaparece el error.

En este punto me surge la siguiente duda: si el campo Horometro viene de la tabla context.LlanHistoria y en dicha tabla, el campo esta ya definido como float, que esta generando el error que indica que estoy convirtiendo este dato en single?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: `context.LlanHistoria` que tipo de dato retorna ???

Comment: Hola @Yussef, mi así esta definido mi context: public class Context : DbContext y dentro de este, así definí mi la tabla LlanHistoria: public DbSet<LlanHistoria> LlanHistoria { get; set; }. Realmente no se que tipo de dato retorna. Me podrías dar indicaciones por favor, par poderte responder.

Comment: Lo raro es que dice decimal.. y ese campo es float... que campo es decimal???

Comment: En la consulta Linq prueba cambiar `select new LlanHistoria {.....}` por `select a`, y me cuentas si funciona así

Comment: @Yussef, al hacer el cambio que nos indicas, nos siegue apareciendo el error: 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Single'. Estoy revisando la base de datos SQL Server para validar contra el modelo que tengo en Visual Studio de dicha base de datos, encontrando lo siguiente: En la base de datos SQL Server, el campo Horometro es del tipo DECIMAL (7, 1). En el modelo de Visual Studio, el campo Horometro es del tipo FLOAT. Creo que esto debe ser lo que genera el error. Teniendo presente que no puedo cambiar el tipo de dato en la base de datos SQL Server, que tipo asigno en Visual Studio?

Comment: usa Decimal tambien en c#.. en general, no se deberia usar float casi nunca, salvo que tengas numeros muy grandes o con muchos decimales...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordial saludo.
Agradecemos a gbianchi por sus comentarios. El error se corrigio cambiando el tipo de dato asignado al campo Horometro, cambiandolo de float a decimal asi:

```
public class LlanHistoria
{
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
}
```